# UWP MapControl and Parcel Boundaries

Tags: uwp, maps, uwp-maps

Is it possible to overlay parcel (property) lines on the UWP Map Control?  I found this blog article about Bing maps which the Map Control uses, but I could not find anything about UWP.  Further, once they are overlaid, I would like to allow the user to select a parcel and store it for later.

https://blogs.bing.com/maps/2010/07/12/overlaying-parcel-boundaries-on-bing-maps

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to overlay parcel data on the UWP map control using similar methods to what you would use for the web control.
First you will need to find a source of the parcel data. The blog links to the DMP source data that provides a raster tile layer. You would need to register with DMP to use this service. Once you have access to the tile layer you would just add it to the map control using the Tile Layer API:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/maps-and-location/overlay-tiled-images
Note that a raster layer is basically static an non-interactive and so you wouldn't be able to do things like select it which you mentioned.
If you have other sources of parcel data you could add the parcels to the map as lines or polygons. See this reference under the section for lines and polygons:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/maps-and-location/display-poi
For example if you have a provider that gives you parcel shapes as GeoJSON you can parse that file and create polygons to add to the map.

Comment: Is there no free source of parcel data for Bing?  Seems disappointing when I can see property lines in Google maps for free...

Comment: The UWP map control currently doesn't display parcel boundaries. It will use parcel data when geocoding, but doesn't show the outlines.